# What is the correct punctuation for quoting a sentence?

Tags: punctuation, quotes

In American English, I would quote what somebody said as in the following example.

> Mark said, "I will not talk to Frank until he apologizes to Mary."

How should I quote a similar sentence in Esperanto? Would the period be included in the quote, as with American English, or should I put it outside the quotes?

Comment: I think that is a typographical decision, rather than a language-specific one, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think, since in Italian quotes are put between _«_ and _»_, which aren't used in English, while in British English you would not put the period inside the quotes.

Comment: Some punctuation issues can be language/culture dependent. Overall, punctuation seems [relatively well-received](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/punctuation) on our English Language site, so let's see if they work equally well here.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I looked in [PMEG](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/index.html), in [the *Helposignoj* section](http://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html) [auxiliary signs].  The paragraph about quotation marks doesn't actually spell out a rule, but follows the British custom of putting the closing quotation mark before the sentence-ending period:

> `“ ”`
>
> Citiloj estas uzataj antaŭ kaj post citaĵo, aŭ antaŭ kaj post vorto, kiu ne estas uzata en sia vera signifo. Jen kelkaj alternativaj formoj: “citaĵo”, "citaĵo", „citaĵo”, «citaĵo», »citaĵo«, ‘citaĵo’. Oni ne metu spacetojn inter citiloj kaj citaĵo. Ne skribu do: “ citaĵo ”. Ordinare oni ne elparolas citilojn, sed por aparte atentigi pri la ĉeesto de citiloj en teksto, kelkaj elparolas komencan citilon kiel cit, kaj finan citilon kiel malcit. Pli klare estas diri citaĵo – fino de citaĵo aŭ simile.

Answer (score 2):

There are no fixed rules for punctuation in Esperanto, and especially with fine details like the one asked about in this question, one can just follow one's own feelings about it.

In the case of the sentence in the question, I would avoid the problem by using a colon before the quotation, in which case putting the full stop inside the quotation becomes completely logical:

Mark said: "I will not talk to Frank until he apologizes to Mary."

Comment: No, the period inside the quotes is used in American English; you don't need to use any colon to make it more logical, nor is _logical_ the criterion used in American English to decide what punctuation put in quotes.

Comment: My usage of "logical" refers to the idea that a quote that is embedded in a sentence should be substitutable by another noun phrase without having to change the rest of the sentence. This is not the case for the American English quoting rule, as substituting the quotation by the word "something yields "Mark said, someting", a sentence that lacks a full stop at the end. In this sense, American English does not follow the logic that a mathematical logician or computer scientist would expect. In the case of doubt, I would try to follow this logic in Esperanto.

Answer (score 1):

It might interest you to see how the magazine MONATO treats quotes:

Parolprezento post la citaĵo

```
sen komo, se la citaĵo finiĝas per interpunkcio:
„Kial vi demandas?” diris Bertie.
„Jes, faru!” diris Mavis.
„Sed kun dudek jaroj, ĉu vi ne ...” komencis Ella.

ne citu simplan punkton ĉe la fino de la citaĵo, sed uzu anstataŭe komon post la citaĵo:
„Vi pravas”, konsentis Mellowkent.
```

Parolprezento meze de la citaĵo

```
Se la parolprezento aperas post ĉeffrazo uzu punkton post la parolprezento:
„Tio estas terura”, diris Jane. „Oni tuj informu vian patrinon.”
„Kiom ridinde!” diris s-ino Sangrail. „Ĉu neniu el iliaj amikoj povis pacigi la kverelon?”
Se la parolprezento aperas meze de citita frazo, kie tiu frazo mem ne havus interpunkcion, metu komojn ekster la citiloj:
„Eble”, diris la amiko, „ĝi estas alia turdo.”
Se la parolprezento aperas post komo aŭ tripunkto, lasu tiun interpunkcion en la unua parto de la citaĵo kaj metu komon post la parolprezento:
„Iam estis eta knabino nomita Bertino,” komencis la fraŭlo, „kiu estis ekterordinare bonkonduta.”
„La respondo estas ...” anoncis la voĉo, „kvardek du!”
Se la parolprezento aperas post punktokomo aŭ dupunkto, lasu tiun interpunkcion en la unua parto de la citaĵo kaj metu punktokomon post la parolprezento:
„Ne ĝenu min per via infaneco babilado;” li komentis al Bertie van Tahn; „mi verkas senmortajn versojn.”
„Mi vendas ĉiajn fruktojn:” li diris; „bananojn, pirojn ...”.
```