# What is a good summary of punctuation rules or habits in Esperanto?

Tags: punctuation

- Marcos Cramer [writes](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/72/4948): "There are no fixed rules for punctuation in Esperanto".
- Cyril Robert Brosch [writes](https://esperanto.stackexchange.com/a/4760/4948): "Faru interpunkcie, kion vi volas."

Maybe this is the right sentiment for a language with an open and tolerant culture. But, even if there are no or few official guidelines: **Is there a resource that attempts to document common punctuation habits of people writing in Esperanto?** I suppose the concept of "house rules" or "style guides" goes against the Esperanto spirit? (Perhaps there are guidelines for contributors to the Esperanto-language version of Wikipedia?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a resource that attempts to document common punctuation habits of people writing in Esperanto?

There is such a resource, indeed:
[Section "Helposignoj"](https://bertilow.com/pmeg/skribo_elparolo/skribo/helposignoj.html) in PMEG.

However, consistent with the statements by Cramer and Brosch, this section averts in its introductory paragraph:

> **Ne ekzistas devigaj reguloj pri ilia uzado en Esperanto.** Tial ili estos ĉi tie nur supraĵe klarigitaj.

Thus, even what's listed there is more what you'd call guidelines than actual rules.